# Manually switch Android BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-bottomnav

Is there a simple way to manually switch between items of a [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html)?

I couldn't find any relevant method in the source code.

Comment: Nope, not yet. It's been noted, though. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225900 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227851

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a temporary workaround for this until an official update addresses this issue.

```
((BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNav.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(ITEM_INDEX).callOnClick();
```

Comment: I took hours to find this. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

A safer alternative to Hamed's solution would be the following:

```
bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(bottomNav.getMenu().getItem(ITEM_INDEX).getItemId());
```